# teamcity "Username or password does not match"

Tags: teamcity

I am getting this error on my teamcity from last three days. We use our domain login credentials to log into teamcity. what might be the problem behind this error.

Answer (score 0):

If your TeamCity has set an [LDAP integration](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/LDAP+Integration), it should detect the right credentials (even if your password recently changed, for instance).

If that is the case, check if:

- your [LDAP configuration](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Typical+LDAP+Configurations) is still a valid one.
- the [LDAP troubleshooting page](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/LDAP+Troubleshooting) (including the `teamcity-ldap.log` file)

That kind of integration also means the [user should not be able to change his/her password](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Managing+your+User+Account).